# Is there a way to have transparency in an element without an information bar popping up?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

When I open my page on a browser in my window without it being on the internet, an information bar always pops up regarding active x. Does this always happen with elements that posses transparency or this just on my computer? lack of plug-in etc.

I have the followgin code:

```
background-color:#666666;
    /* for IE */
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    /* CSS3 standard */
    opacity:0.6;
```

Comment: This CSS should not cause an ActiveX warning popup (AFAIK, or is IE *this* weird?). Are you using an ActiveX element on the page?

Comment: @deceze - IE uses ActiveX for filters, which is a good and bad thing.  Bad because it's caused issues since the dawn of time (time == internet).  Good because technically IE was ___miles___ ahead of any other browser and could do most things that CSS3 can do now in IE4, though it was insanely complicated to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens in the local security zone. If you put this on a webserver you shouldn't get that popup.